# ember-cli tests fail to load multiple needs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli v0.0.44

Here is my test:

```
import {
  moduleFor,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('controller:cpe-admin', 'CpeAdminController', {
  needs: [ 'controller:application', 'controller:cpe-vendor-summary' ]
});

test('it exists', function() {
  var controller = this.subject();
  ok(controller);
});
```

Here is the error that is produced when I run the command ember test:

```
not ok 115 PhantomJS 1.9 - CpeAdminController: it exists
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Died on test #1     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:412
                at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:278)
                at :17
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:70
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:14: <(subclass of Ember.Controller):ember286> needs [ controller:cpeVendorSummary ] but it could not be found
```

The file app/controller/cpe-vendor-summary.js exists within my project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the controller in app/controller or app/controllers?

Comment: Have you confirmed it's still an issue with the latest ember-cli?

Comment: Have not but I will and I'll provide an update here.

Comment: Tested with a newer version of ember-cli and its not a problem.

Comment: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2507

Comment: I could have told you that 4 days ago if you posted the controller code here :) Glad you got it worked out though.